# What Does the Jump Key Do in Bumper Cars?

Tags: team-fortress-2

Pressing the jump key during the bumper car games causes the car to bounce slightly. What is the purpose of this maneuver?

Answer (score 2):

You jump in a bumper car. You can use it to dodge attacks. It's not amazingly useful, the right click boost is better.